# Let a and b be nonzero integers. Prove that there exist a unique q, r also integers such that a=bq+r and 0<=r<|b|

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let a and b be nonzero integers. Prove that there exist a unique q, r also integers such that a=bq+r and 0 <= r<|b|

The number theory book ask me to prove this but I realize that r can be <0 for example take a= 10 and b=-3 then 10/-3=-3.3333333 therefore q must =-4 because q <= a/b  as a result q*b =12 and then r must be negative 2. Where did I go wrong?

I apologize for the format I tried using \le but it did not work and I wanted this to be understandable.

Thanks

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is: Nobody said $q\le\frac ab$.

Comment: Oh I realized what i did wrong thanks for the help, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take $r=\frac{10}{-3}$. It's written in the statement that $r$ must be an integer.